# ActiveRecord has_many through two models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have the following context:

4 models:

- Project
- Investor
- Subscription
- ExternalSubscription

A `project` shall have many `investors` through either `subscriptions` or `external_subscriptions`.

I currently have a method that does something like this: `Investor.where(id: (subscription_ids + external_subscription_ids))`.

My goal is to have a `has_many` relationship (and precisely use the `has_many` activerecord feature) to get the same result.
How can I acheive this? Is it even possible?

Thanks!

```
Project

[Associations]
  has_many :subscriptions
  has_many :external_subscriptions

[Table description]
  create_table "projects", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end
```

---

```
Investor

[Associations]
  has_many :subscriptions
  has_many :external_subscriptions

[Table description]
  create_table "investors", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end
```

---

```
Subscription

[Associations]
  belongs_to :project
  belongs_to :investor

[Table description]
  create_table "subscriptions", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "project_id"
    t.integer "investor_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["investor_id"], name: "index_subscriptions_on_investor_id"
    t.index ["project_id"], name: "index_subscriptions_on_project_id"
  end
```

---

```
ExternalSubscription

[Associations]
  belongs_to :project
  belongs_to :investor

[Table description]
  create_table "external_subscriptions", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "project_id"
    t.integer "investor_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["investor_id"], name: "index_external_subscriptions_on_investor_id"
    t.index ["project_id"], name: "index_external_subscriptions_on_project_id"
  end
```

I'm on rails 5.0.x

## Edit

My real models are more complex than that. Here, I'm just showing the relationships to make it easy to discuss, but I can't merge `subscriptions` and `external_subscriptions` into the same model.

Comment: Table structure of both `Subscription` and `ExternalSubscription` are same. You can use Single Table Inheritance (http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#single-table-inheritance)  or simple `subscription_type` enum field to make two separate has_many relationships `subscriptions`, `external_subscriptions` along with `all_subscriptions`.

Comment: It is achievable using a SQL VIEW doing a `UNION ALL` on both tables, then `has_many through` that view

Comment: The tables are the same. Maybe you just need a discriminent on this table (like a boolean flag `external`) on the subscriptions table, and then update your logic accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved my issue with an SQL view doing a UNION thanks to @MrYoshiji's comment.

Here's the POC: https://github.com/yoones/rails-has_many-through-view

Answer (score 1):

As it seems you don't need different information in your subscriptions and external_subscriptions (both tables have the same fields), I would use only one model and table, and classify subscriptions based on a new field in the table. By using appropriate scopes you can access all associated models easily.

**Project**

```
class Project < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :subscriptions
  has_many :external_subscriptions, -> { external }, class_name: "Subscription"
  has_many :normal_subscriptions, -> { normal }, class_name: "Subscription"
  has_many :investors, through: :subscriptions
  has_many :external_investors, through: :external_subscriptions, :source => :investor
  has_many :normal_investors, through: :normal_subscriptions, :source => :investor

end
```

**Investor**

```
class Investor < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :subscriptions
  has_many :projects, through: : subscriptions
end
```

**Subscription**

```
class Subscription < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :project
  belongs_to :investor
  enum type: [ :external, :normal ]

  scope :external, -> { where(type: :external) }
  scope :normal, -> { where(type: :normal) } 
end
```

Then you can access different project investors as:

```
project = Project.first.
project.investors #all
project.external_investors #only external
project.normal_investors #only normal
```